# Splitting value in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am writing a code that represents recombinant DNA process. I am hitting a brick wall on how to move forward with my cut and connect method. I have come as far as writing a while loop that searches for the index of the enzyme that we are looking for, but now I've hit a brick wall.

My class represents a linked list, and it is meant to do the following:

- First it gets a DNA strand represented as a String and places that whole 
  String in the first node of the LinkedList.
- Than it searches for a specific enzyme sequence in the strand (String in the 
  node) (the while loop in cutAndConnect)
- Than it needs to cut the String at that point, and at the end of the enzyme, 
  cutting the enzyme out.
- Than it needs to place the connection in a new node, and the part of the 
  strand(String) that came after the enzyme sequence in another new node.
- And it needs to do that for the whole strand, so for all the times that the 
  specific enzyme sequence occurs in the strand.

I've also added all of the methods that I haven't putt any body inn yet. DnaStreng is the interface that is used in this project, but it haven't added the interface into this question because it basically only contains the javascript for all of the methods.

I'm hoping some of you can help me move forward with this. I have the following code:

```
public class LinkStreng implements DnaStreng{

    public static LinkStreng STRING_LEEG = new LinkStreng();
    private String dna;
    List<String> dnaList= new LinkedList<String>();
    Node head;
    Node next;

    /* Makes a new String with length 0*/
    public LinkStreng(){
        this("");
    }

    /* Makes a new LinkStreng with the given DNA(in the main class there is a 
     filechooser used.*/
    public LinkStreng(String hetDna){
     dna = hetDna;
     head = null;
     Node firstNode = new Node(hetDna);
    }

    /*Counts the number of Nodes in the list*/
    public int getCount(){
        Node temp = head;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp!= null){
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    / ** Simulates a cut by a restriction enzyme. Seeks the first occurrence
    * of the enzyme in this strand and removes the enzyme and everything after it
    * coming. Returns the part after the enzyme as a new strand. If the
    * enzyme does not occur in this strength, it remains unchanged and an
    * returned empty strand will be returned.
    * @param enzyme the string to search for
    * @return the part of this strength after the enzyme */
    public DnaStreng cutWith(String enzym) {
        // Here I get an error that it cannot find the getCount method
        if (dnaList.getCount() >1){
            throw new RuntimeException("Linkstreng heeft meer dan 1 node");
        } else {             
        int enzymBegin = dna.indexOf(enzym);
        if (enzymBegin == -1) return STRENG_LEEG;

        // Enzyme found: cut
        String dnaAchterEnzym = dna.substring(enzymBegin + enzym.length());
        DnaStreng achter = new LinkStreng(dnaAchterEnzym);
        initialiseer(dna.substring(0, enzymBegin));
        return achter;
        }
    }



     /** Cut this strand wherever the enzyme occurs and connect the
     * pieces by placing the connection between them.
     * @param enzym the string to search for
     * @param connectionthe DNA that will replace the enzyme
     * @return the new strand (the original strand remains unchanged) */
    public DnaStreng cutAndConnect(String enzym, String connection) {
        // With this getCount I get the same error
        if (dnaList.getCount() > 1){
            throw new RuntimeException("Linkstreng heeft meer dan 1 node");
        }
        String teSplitsen = " " + dna + " ";
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < dna.length()){
        dna.indexOf(enzym, i);
        i++;
        }

        return new LinkStreng();

    }

    /* Gives the number of letters in the strand */
    public long lengte() {
      // this method isn't working as well, it returns the wrong number
       return dnaList.toString().length();
    }

    /** Initializes this strand by inserting the DNA, any
     * previous data is erased. Does not check for valid DNA letters.
     * @param dna the DNA string placed in this strand * /
    public void initialiseer(String hetDna) {

    }



    /** Adds the addition behind this strand.
     * @param addition the strand being added */
    public void voegToe(DnaStreng addition) {

    }

    /** Adds the addition behind this strand.
     * @param addition the strand being added */
    public void voegToe(String addition) {

    }


    public String toString(){
        Node current = head;
        StringBuilder recombinant = new StringBuilder((CharSequence) dnaList);
        while(current != null){
            recombinant = recombinant.append(head.value);
            current = current.next;
        }
        return recombinant.toString();
    }
}

public class Node {
    public Node next;
    public String value;

    public Node(String s){
        value = s;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Evelyn. The code sample you have posted appears to have compile errors. Could you eliminate those by editing the post? I would also suggest paying attention to formatting. I also find it hard to understand what exactly you are struggling with. If you could explain what you expect to achieve and what you currently have it would help to breach that gap.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post so that now all the code that I have so far is in it. I have compile compile problem because it can't find the getCount method, I'm hoping somebody can help me solve that too. I have also clarrified what I need to achieve with this class

Comment: Just to help you with `getCount()`: to get a number of elements in a `List` use `size()`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be a mixture of contradictive approaches that aim to achieve the same goal.

For instance:

```
List<String> dnaList = new LinkedList<String>();
Node head;
Node next;
```

- On one hand, the first line in this example suggests you're trying to use the `LinkedList` from the Java standard library.
- On the other hand, the next two lines are evidence of an attempt to have a custom implementation of a linked list data structure.

There are more examples of why this code isn't working, I believe this one is convincing enough.

Generally, to avoid the chaotic approach to write the entire program at once (Rome wasn't built in one day!) I would strongly recommend working at one small bit at a time and write tests for each bit.

I will demonstrate the proposed approach and move step-by-step through the list of yours:

> 1. First, it gets a DNA strand represented as a String and places that whole String in the first node of the LinkedList.

In all likelihood, you don't want to store the entire string in one node. What you really want is storing a character (which is just one letter, whereas a string is a sequence of letters).

```
public class DNAStrand {
    Node head = null;

    public DNAStrand(final String dnaStrand) {
        if (dnaStrand.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // Initialise the first node of a list
        Node currentNode = new Node(dnaStrand.charAt(0));

        // Assign the first Node to `head`
        head = currentNode;

        // Iterate through the rest of string storing remaining characters
        for (int i = 1; i < dnaStrand.length(); i++) {
            final Node nextNode = new Node(dnaStrand.charAt(i));
            currentNode.next = nextNode;
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        public Node next;
        public char value;

        public Node(char s) {
            value = s;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    // Tests are located below this line
    private static void testDnaStrandIsPlaceDInTheFirstNodeOfLinkedList() {
        final DNAStrand dnaStrand = new DNAStrand("acgt");
        if (dnaStrand.head == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("The head is null after creating an object from a string");
        }

        List<Character> actualString = new ArrayList<>();
        Node listPointer = dnaStrand.head;
        do {
            actualString.add(listPointer.value);
            listPointer = listPointer.next;
        } while (listPointer != null);

        if (!"acgt".equals(actualString.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()))) {
            throw new AssertionError("Wrong value in the first node, expected: 'agct;, got: "
                    + dnaStrand.head.value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testDnaStrandIsPlaceDInTheFirstNodeOfLinkedList();
    }
}
```

The `main` method in my example executes the test `testDnaStrandIsPlaceDInTheFirstNodeOfLinkedList`. That test makes sure that a simple contract is met. As the code grows bigger you'd better off adding more tests, to ensure you don't break old functionality and prove that the new code works well.

> - Than it searches for a specific enzyme sequence in the strand (String in the node) (the while loop in cutAndConnect)
> - Then it needs to cut the String at that point, and at the end of the enzyme, cutting the enzyme out.
> - Then it needs to place the connection in a new node, and the part of the strand(String) that came after the enzyme sequence in another new node.
> - And it needs to do that for the whole strand, so for all the times that the specific enzyme sequence occurs in the strand.

Essentially, this is a description of one single method. I will add a `cutAndConnect()` which does what you ask for along with the tests that explain/prove it works.

```
public class DNAStrand {
    Node head = null;

    public DNAStrand(final String dnaStrand) {
        if (dnaStrand.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        head = stringToListNodes(dnaStrand);
    }

    private static class Node {
        public Node next;
        public Node previous;
        public char value;

        public Node(char character, final Node previousNode) {
            this.value = character;
            this.next = null;
            this.previous = previousNode;
        }
    }

    private Node stringToListNodes(final String string) {
        // Initialise the first node of a list
        Node currentNode = new Node(string.charAt(0), null);

        // Assign the first Node to `head`
        final Node head = currentNode;

        // Iterate through the rest of string storing remaining characters
        for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
            final Node nextNode = new Node(string.charAt(i), currentNode);
            currentNode.next = nextNode;
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }

        return head;
    }

    public void cutAndConnect(final String enzyme, final String linker) {
        if (linker.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linked can't be empty");
        }
        Node potentialEnzymeStart = head;
        while (potentialEnzymeStart != null) {
            Node currentNode = potentialEnzymeStart;
            boolean dismatchFound = false;

            for (char enzymeSymbol : enzyme.toCharArray()) {
                if (enzymeSymbol != currentNode.value) {
                    dismatchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }

            if (!dismatchFound) {
                // The enzyme does match the sequence
                // The DNA has the following structure <left piece> <enzyme> <right piece>. Find the left and right piece nodes
                Node leftPieceEnd = potentialEnzymeStart.previous;
                if (leftPieceEnd == null) {
                    // Replace the current head
                    head = stringToListNodes(linker);
                } else {
                    // Simply connect a node of a doubly linked list
                    final Node linkedInAFormOfList = stringToListNodes(linker);
                    leftPieceEnd.next = linkedInAFormOfList;
                    linkedInAFormOfList.previous = leftPieceEnd;
                }

                Node connectionPoint = leftPieceEnd == null ? head : leftPieceEnd.next;
                for (int i = 0; i < linker.length() - 1; ++i) {
                    connectionPoint = connectionPoint.next;
                }

                Node rightPieceStart = potentialEnzymeStart;
                for (int i = 0; i < enzyme.length(); ++i) {
                    rightPieceStart = rightPieceStart.next;
                }

                if (rightPieceStart != null) {
                    connectionPoint.next = rightPieceStart;
                    rightPieceStart.previous = connectionPoint;
                }
            }

            potentialEnzymeStart = potentialEnzymeStart.next;
        }
    }

    // Tests are located below this line
    private static void testDnaStrandIsPlaceDInTheFirstNodeOfLinkedList() {
        final DNAStrand dnaStrand = new DNAStrand("acgt");
        if (dnaStrand.head == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("The head is null after creating an object from a string");
        }

        List<Character> actualString = new ArrayList<>();
        Node listPointer = dnaStrand.head;
        do {
            actualString.add(listPointer.value);
            listPointer = listPointer.next;
        } while (listPointer != null);

        if (!"acgt".equals(actualString.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()))) {
            throw new AssertionError("Wrong value in the first node, expected: 'agct`, got: "
                    + dnaStrand.head.value);
        }
    }

    private static void testCutAndConnectCutEntireDNAString() {
        final DNAStrand dnaStrand = new DNAStrand("acgt");
        dnaStrand.cutAndConnect("acgt", "a");
        if (dnaStrand.head == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("The head of a list must not be null");
        }

        if (dnaStrand.head.value != 'a') {
            throw new AssertionError("The head of the list contains wrong value, expected: 'a`, got: " +
                    dnaStrand.head.value);
        }

        if (dnaStrand.head.next != null) {
            throw new AssertionError("The list must have the length 1");
        }
    }

    private static void testCutAndConnectCutTheMiddleOfDNAString() {
        final DNAStrand dnaStrand = new DNAStrand("acca");
        dnaStrand.cutAndConnect("cc", "g");

        List<Character> actualString = new ArrayList<>();
        Node listPointer = dnaStrand.head;
        do {
            actualString.add(listPointer.value);
            listPointer = listPointer.next;
        } while (listPointer != null);

        if (!"aga".equals(actualString.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()))) {
            throw new AssertionError("Wrong value in the list, expected: 'aga`, got: "
                    + dnaStrand.head.value);
        }
    }

    private static void testCutAndConnectCutMultipleOccurrencesOfAnEnzyme() {
        final DNAStrand dnaStrand = new DNAStrand("accacca");
        dnaStrand.cutAndConnect("cc", "g");

        List<Character> actualString = new ArrayList<>();
        Node listPointer = dnaStrand.head;
        do {
            actualString.add(listPointer.value);
            listPointer = listPointer.next;
        } while (listPointer != null);

        if (!"agaga".equals(actualString.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()))) {
            throw new AssertionError("Wrong value in the list, expected: 'agaga`, got: "
                    + dnaStrand.head.value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testDnaStrandIsPlaceDInTheFirstNodeOfLinkedList();
        testCutAndConnectCutEntireDNAString();
        testCutAndConnectCutTheMiddleOfDNAString();
        testCutAndConnectCutMultipleOccurrencesOfAnEnzyme();
    }
}
```

I added more tests, tests are pretty good at describing what's going on. I would suggest starting to read the od from them.

Does it look like something you wanted to achieve?

Generally speaking, the question you've posted doesn't meet the StackOverflow criteria. Simply because it isn't a question, but more of a 'my code isn't working' :)

Next time, try to narrow down the scope of your question and provide a minimal code example.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so much that I can work off of now. The only thing is that I really do have to put the initial DNA string into one node, but I can still get some inspiration from the cutAndConnect method that you wrote. Thank you!!

Comment: @Evelyn I wonder what is the point of storing a String in a Node? Can you describe the expectations from the `cutAndConnect` method in case every Node stores a whole String?

Comment: The expectations for cutAndConnect are as I described above, it needs to search in the string that is in the node.

Comment: @Evelyn from what I understand, it needs to visit each node and cut an enzyme within every string. As a matter of fact, strings are immutable in java. You certainly could construct a modified string and assign it to each node though. However, the linked list of characters is more efficient and probably cleaner as an approach. I reckon `List<LinkedList<Character>>` would be a reasonable two-dimensional structure in this case